# asyncio server fails to write to the client via a loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Provided is a MWE that demonstrates the issue. When sending bytes to a client in a loop using asyncio, the server will send on the first iteration, but subsequent iterations it will simply buffer the bytes and never send. The client will just wait for more bytes but for some reason the bytes don't arrive. If the server program is closed with SIGINT (ctrl+c), the server will dump the buffer out to the client all at once.

```
import asyncio
import socket
from time import sleep
import sys

class server_protocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_closed = True

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport
        self.write_counter = 0
        self.connection_closed = False
        
    def write_loop(self):
        while not self.connection_closed:
            self.write_counter+=1
            print(self.write_counter,'Writing bytes, Buffer Size:',self.transport.get_write_buffer_size())
            self.transport.write(b'AhXTMkHrJHdExaKBLmkvTnvRduENcusjnRnrBAHtjnUMtdjxsnKgDRtpDMjncFczrqwjrSrVNwxtBSmmLJnFAfkgbDwEuBAcdVMCLVeMuSXfxyYRdaNvvEhEFnGWNNtk')
            sleep(1)
        self.transport.close()
        
    def data_received(self,data):
        self.write_loop()
        
    def connection_lost(self,exc):
        print("Connection lost")
        self.connection_closed = True
        
    def eof_received(self):
        print("EOF received")
        self.connection_closed = True
        
def client(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', port)
    print('connecting to {}:{}'.format(*server_address))
    sock.connect(server_address)
    try:
        # Send data
        message = b'start'
        print('sending {!r}'.format(message))
        sock.sendall(message)
        while True:
            print('Receiving')
            data = sock.recv(256)
            print('Received {!r}'.format(data))
            if len(data) == 0:
                break

    finally:
        print('closing socket')
        sock.close()
        
async def main(type,port):
    if type == 'server':
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        server = await loop.create_server(lambda: server_protocol(),'localhost', port)
        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()
    elif type == 'client':
        client(port)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2])))
    else:
        print('provide argument \'server\' or \'client\' and port')
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Updated answer based on [dirn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978961/dirn)'s comment

The problem is with `write_loop`. It needs to be an `async` method run with `asyncio.ensure_future` and `sleep` needs to be `asyncio.sleep`. The original example has `write_loop` preventing the event loop from being able to run anything else.

Corrected MWE:

```
import asyncio
import socket
import sys

class server_protocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_closed = True

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport
        self.write_counter = 0
        self.connection_closed = False
        
    async def write_loop(self):
        while not self.connection_closed:
            self.write_counter+=1
            print(self.write_counter,'Writing bytes, Buffer Size:',self.transport.get_write_buffer_size())
            self.transport.write(b'AhXTMkHrJHdExaKBLmkvTnvRduENcusjnRnrBAHtjnUMtdjxsnKgDRtpDMjncFczrqwjrSrVNwxtBSmmLJnFAfkgbDwEuBAcdVMCLVeMuSXfxyYRdaNvvEhEFnGWNNtk')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.transport.close()
        
    def data_received(self,data):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.write_loop())
        
    def connection_lost(self,exc):
        print("Connection lost")
        self.connection_closed = True
        
    def eof_received(self):
        print("EOF received")
        self.connection_closed = True
        
def client(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost', port)
    print('connecting to {}:{}'.format(*server_address))
    sock.connect(server_address)
    try:
        # Send data
        message = b'start'
        print('sending {!r}'.format(message))
        sock.sendall(message)
        while True:
            print('Receiving')
            data = sock.recv(256)
            print('Received {!r}'.format(data))
            if len(data) == 0:
                break

    finally:
        print('closing socket')
        sock.close()
        
async def main(type,port):
    if type == 'server':
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        server = await loop.create_server(lambda: server_protocol(),'localhost', port)
        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()
    elif type == 'client':
        client(port)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1],int(sys.argv[2])))
    else:
        print('provide argument \'server\' or \'client\' and port')
```

Comment: It's not so much that `sleep` is synchronous but rather than `write_loop` is (in the OP). Without a way for it to yield control back to the event loop, nothing else would ever get a chance to run.